# Assistance with website recreation for project

Tags: php, html

I dont know if this is the right place to post this, but i need help with my project for school.

I need to recreate this page in HTML for a school project to create a store with order tracking page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMZIr.png

i choos this one, and i need help recreating it in pure HTML.
It looks neat and really detailed. i tried making a purchase on their original site and saving the order page, but it seems to be encrypted, so i cannot get any of the original html files.

Comment: Have you tried to create it yet? You need to at least attempt to solve the problem. If you face any problems, paste your code here and the community will try to help you in the best way possible. If you don't know where to start, start by learning the basics of HTML and HTML tables.

Comment: i attempted it, and it just looks terrible, im still working on it, ill post a code when i feel comfortable with how it looks, so yall can assist me

Comment: Divide your problem to smaller pieces and work on each piece, if you get stucked post a specific question and include what you've done so far along with your expected result. This way you can get the proper help you need